# A Measure take long load time/ fail

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

My back-end contains millions lines of data. It loads quickly when it is all in one visualization table without any filters.
[image]

Now I need to identify which columns have been left blank by the user and point them out, so I have this measure.

```
C_Blank = 
SUMX(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SIT,
        "Count",
        var Direction = SIT[Direction]
        var INCO = SIT[INCOTERM]
        var res1 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {SIT[Consol Number],SIT[ETD],SIT[ATD],SIT[ETA],SIT[Estimated Pickup],SIT[Interim Receipt Date],SIT[Actual Pickup]},
                NOT ISBLANK([Value])))
        var res2 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER(
                {SIT[Consol Number],SIT[ETD],SIT[ATD],SIT[ETA],SIT[ATA],SIT[Estimated Pickup],SIT[Interim Receipt Date],
                 SIT[Actual Pickup],SIT[Estimated Delivery],SIT[Actual Delivery]},
                 NOT ISBLANK([Value])))
        var res3 = COUNTROWS(
            filter(
                {SIT[ATA],SIT[Estimated Delivery],SIT[Actual Delivery]},
                NOT ISBLANK([Value])))

        var res4 = COUNTROWS(
            FILTER({SIT[Estimated Pickup],SIT[Interim Receipt Date],SIT[Actual Pickup],SIT[Estimated Delivery],SIT[Actual Delivery]},
                  NOT ISBLANK([Value])))
        
         return  
        if (Direction = "Domestic" || SIT[Transport Mode] ="ROA", res4,
        if (Direction = "Export" && LEFT(INCO, 1) = "D" || (Direction = "Import" && LEFT(INCO, 1) = "D") , res2 , 
        if (Direction = "Export" && NOT(LEFT(INCO, 1) = "D") , res1,
        if (Direction = "Import" && NOT(LEFT(INCO, 1) = "D") , res3))))),
    [Count])
```

However, after I put this measure into the table, it took extremely long time to load, and sometimes it would fail to load.
[image]

Fail to load:

[image]

Could this measure be modified to speed up performance?

Appreciate any help provided!

Comment: Is it possible to share pbix file? Lots of details to take into accounts. We need to see your data model, metadata, relationships... As far as I can see, You are iterating large tables with multiple FILTER() function. Also, After RETURN, Instead of using IF, SWITCH() is a much better option.

Comment: Also is this import or DirectQuery?  How big are the tables?  For mere millions of rows you shouldn't need DirectQuery.  And such complicated measures are going to be a challenge in DirectQuery mode.